# Adding data to a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

This is something I have never really understood, so forgive me if it seems very basic. What is the correct/best way of adding data to a CharField model so that it is available in my DB? Should it be as `choices` below for this type of data?

I want to store the below URLs in my DB and make it possible to select one at random in my views.py

When I run the below code I get

> URLS = 0

Should that not be 9?

**models.py**

```
class URLs(models.Model):

    URL_CHOICES = (
                   ('one', '/urlone/'),
                   ('two', '/urltwo/'), 
                   ('three', '/urlthree/'), 
                   ('four', '/urlfour/'), 
                   ('five', '/urlfive/'),
                   ('six', '/urlsix/'), 
                   ('seven', '/urlseven/'),
                   ('eight', '/urleight/'),
                   ('nine', '/urlnine/'),)

    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=URL_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self
```

**views.py**

```
from survey.models import URLs

def begin(request):
    surveyurls = URLs.objects.all().count()

    print 'URLS = ', surveyurls
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices) argument for a `ModelField` works differently than you seem to assume.

With `choices`, you can limit the accepted values for a model instance. It doesn't actually write anything into the database. To populate your database, you can use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/).

Answer (score 1):

In the model you define how your data looks. Django will use this information to build your database structure.

If you want fill the database right from the start you should look at this: [HowTo - Initial Data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/)

Answer (score 0):

the best way it's by the migration data file:
here's a example:

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('procesos', '0020_auto_20150703_1656'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("UPDATE procesos_busquedainmueble SET tipo_inmueble_id=(filtros::json->>'tipo_inmueble')::int;"),
```